# Is it possible to write code for Coded UI Tests without having the application?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Is it possible to write code for Coded UI Tests without having the application?
Just with the requirements can u prepare Coded UI record and assert method before getting the application?

Comment: Not really. That would be like knitting without yarn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

- You can write general methods that take UITestControls as parameters. Then when you get the application you want to test you can record the UI elements, add them to the UIMap then pass the controls to your functions.
- You can try recording on a dummy application to have the recordings and assertions. Then record the controls from the real application. In the UMap editor you can change the UI Actions' UI Control property to the "live" controls.

Unfortunately these methods won't save you much time cause you will only be able to make skeletons for your tests and you will still have to do most of the recordings on the application you want to test.